# Travis conditional build - How to skip deploy stage except master branch

Tags: docker, github, build, travis-ci

I have two stages in the following travis configuration file.

- test - This run tests on all branches.
- deploy - This run deploy script and push docker images to Docker hub. This should run only on master branch.

I intended to run the `deploy` stage only by using conditional build feature on `master` branch but the `deploy` stage is still running on other branches as well.
How can I skip `deploy` stage except master branch?

```
language: java
services:
  - docker

before_cache:
  <cache clearning>

cache:
  directories:
  <cache directories>

stages:
  - test
  - name: deploy
    if: branch == master

docker_login:
  before_script: 
  <before command here>

jobs:
  include:
  - stage: test
    script:
    <test command here>
  - stage: deploy
    before_script: *docker_login
    name: build docker
    script:
    <deploy command here>
```

**Updated**

I had to change like as follows

```
if: branch == master AND (NOT (type IN (push, pull_request)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- This works.
- Skip `deploy` stage run on pull request to base repository but it run on `main` branch for fork.

```
if: branch = master AND type = push AND fork = false
```